# Appium Tests Don't Run on AWS Device Farm but Run Fine Locally

Tags: android, maven, appium, aws-device-farm

I have written some tests for an Android application using Appium with Java and TestNG. My tests run fine locally on an emulator, but when I upload them to device farm my test always fails. I have simplified my test as much as possible and it still does not work. Currently, the test I am trying to run finds and clicks the permission allow button on the prompt that appears upon opening the app. Code:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class MyAppTest {

    public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void Setup(){

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
    @Test
    public void authTest() {        

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")));   

    MobileElement allowBtn = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"));
    allowBtn.click();

    }

@AfterTest
    public void teardown() {

        driver.quit();

    }
```

Watching the video that Device Farm provides, I can see that it opens my app and immediately closes it. It does not even wait like it should. I am at a loss here and have spent far to many hours with no luck. The only thing I can think of is something is happening with Maven when I am zipping up my file before uploading it to device farm. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: Appium server logs (From Device Farm)

```
   2018-08-09 19:21:52:790 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["id","com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f"]
2018-08-09 19:21:52:823 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-09 19:21:52:825 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-09 19:21:52:840 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
2018-08-09 19:21:52:936 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":true}}
2018-08-09 19:21:52:960 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":true}}
2018-08-09 19:21:52:962 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2018-08-09 19:21:52:963 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
2018-08-09 19:21:52:964 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
2018-08-09 19:21:52:965 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:52:966 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:52:967 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
2018-08-09 19:21:52:976 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:52:977 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
2018-08-09 19:21:52:978 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
2018-08-09 19:21:52:978 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:52:979 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:52:980 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
2018-08-09 19:21:52:981 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:52:981 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
2018-08-09 19:21:52:982 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2018-08-09 19:21:53:004 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: []
2018-08-09 19:21:53:018 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f/elements 200 247 ms - 74 
2018-08-09 19:21:53:600 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f/elements {"using":"id","value":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"}
2018-08-09 19:21:53:602 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["id","com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f"]
2018-08-09 19:21:53:604 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-09 19:21:53:615 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-09 19:21:53:618 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
2018-08-09 19:21:53:620 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":true}}
2018-08-09 19:21:53:651 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":true}}
2018-08-09 19:21:53:652 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2018-08-09 19:21:53:652 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
2018-08-09 19:21:53:653 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
2018-08-09 19:21:53:653 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:53:666 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:53:667 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
2018-08-09 19:21:53:679 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:54:032 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (1)
2018-08-09 19:21:54:042 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2018-08-09 19:21:54:045 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: [{"ELEMENT":"1"}]
2018-08-09 19:21:54:064 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f/elements 200 446 ms - 89 
2018-08-09 19:21:54:079 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=1, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-09 19:21:54:085 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"1"}]}
2018-08-09 19:21:54:160 - [HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f {}
2018-08-09 19:21:54:162 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f"]
2018-08-09 19:21:54:163 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1533842514163 (19:21:54 GMT+0000 (UTC))
2018-08-09 19:21:54:174 - [Appium] Removing session e27184af-22d3-4a4e-8505-f2e47b35dc7f from our master session list
2018-08-09 19:21:54:178 - [debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
```

Successful Appium server log from local test:

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["id","com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (1)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=1, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"1"}]}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: [{"ELEMENT":"1"}]
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/elements 200 7373 ms - 89
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element/1/displayed {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.elementDisplayed() with args: ["1","8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b"]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getAttribute","params":{"attribute":"displayed","elementId":"1"}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getAttribute","params":{"attribute":"displayed","elementId":"1"}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: getAttribute
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.elementDisplayed() result: true
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element/1/displayed 200 295 ms - 76
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"true"}
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element {"using":"id","value":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"2"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element 200 18 ms - 87
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"}}
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element/2/click {"id":"2"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args: ["2","8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b"]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: click
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: true
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element/2/click 200 3223 ms - 76
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element/2/click {"id":"2"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args: ["2","8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b"]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: click
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: true
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b/element/2/click 200 3377 ms - 76
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1533841411213 (14:03:31 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[Appium] Removing session 8e38c406-877d-470b-a6c8-7df870d0a94b from our master session list
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
```

Comment: Can you post the appium server logs?

Comment: The appium server logs will tell us what the issue is. If the app opened the pom file notes the issue. Seems like the element being waited for does exists. 

Is there a permission popup in the device farm video?

Comment: @jmp Thanks for your response, I have edited the original post to contain the section where Appium tries and fails to find the button. I could not post the entire log because it was too long. Yes, the permission allow button appears in the video. Let me know if you want any other information. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like Appium is able to find the element after a couple of tries.
`2018-08-07 15:54:11:882 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: [{"ELEMENT":"1"}]
2018-08-07 15:54:11:925 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/478d0811-eb43-4fbf-b0c3-d2f4c742aaec/elements 200 1951 ms - 89 `

Could you post a small code snippet of what's happening on this line?
`com.mycompany.app.MyAppTest.authTest line 84` 

Also, from the log I believe these tests are using `uiautomator` as the automationName. Can you try using UIAutomator2 and see if that helps?

Comment: also for comparison, could you post the Appium server logs from the local execution where this is successful?

Comment: another thing that's interesting that I just noticed is that the log show `driver.findElements()` being called but that's not what the code sample shows. It's calling `findElement`.

It looks like this log is also using the `AppiumDriver` and not the android one from the code sample. 

Could you repost the Appium Server logs from that's using the same code sample as above?

Comment: @jmp My apologies, I have tweaked the code and re-ran it so many times I must have gotten them confused. I have updated the original post to include the correct logs for both the Device Farm Appium Server and the logs from a successful local test. Both of the logs are using the exact code included in the post (besides the capabilities set in the local test). As for line 84, that is the wait for visibility of the element:  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")));`

Comment: @jmp As far as UIAutomator, nowhere is my code do I include anything about that. I assumed that was run automatically by Appium. How do I change it to run UIAutomator2?

Comment: It looks like locally the tests are calling `AppiumDriver.findElement()` whereas in Device Farm the tests call `AppiumDriver.findElements()`. In Device Farm the element is found on the second call to this REST endpoint, however the session is deleted afterword without clicking on it. Locally, the element is found and then the click REST resource is invoked. If the same test package was used in both cases then it may be the case that `@AfterTest` is running before the click action can run in Device Farm. Can you chance that to `@AfterClass` and see if that helps?

Comment: also, to add the capability automationName you would append the DesiredCapabilities object similar to this: `DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities(); dc.setCapability("automationName","UIAutomator2");`
Then use that dc object in the instantiation of the driver.

Comment: @jmp I have tried both changing `@AfterTest` to `@AfterClass` and adding the capability to use UIAutomator2. Neither of these did the trick. I am still seeing the same issue as before.

Comment: Thanks for trying that. Given all the info so far the device farm logs show that the click action didn't happen but it was able to find the element. This suggests that it's not the same tests as we're running locally. Could you please double check that the same tests are running in d farm as when running locally?

Comment: @jmp The only difference between the tests run locally and the tests run on device farm is the desired capabilities. Whenever I change anything in the code I run it locally on an emulator to make sure it works, comment out the capabilities, and then create the maven build and upload it to device farm. To my understanding, device farm uses its own desired capabilities. Could the issue have to deal with this?

Comment: It could depending on the capability being used. How is the test package being built? Is it using the same command as the sample tests? `mvn clean package -DskipTests`

The capabilities Device farm uses should be a the top of the appium server output. 

In this case, it seems the code for clicking on the button isn&#39;t present in the device farm tests since the click endpoint isn&#39;t called as in the local tests.

Comment: @jmp Yes that is the command being used. I just reviewed the Appium server logs and nothing seems to be the issue with the capabilities. The appPackage and appActivity are both the same as well as the device version. The only difference (besides the device name and udid) is the capability `useKeystore: true` which seems to be something that has to do with security.

Comment: Would you have a sample app which presents the same popup? I want to try and reproduce this issue.

Comment: @jmp Sorry for the delay, but yes I have put together a sample app that is experiencing the exact same issue as the one above. The sample app is a simple "Hello World" that prompts permission for the app to read contacts upon opening. How would you like me to send you the apk?

Comment: Hi @Dallas, No worries. Would it be possible to upload the apk to a github repo or other free hosting solutions?

Comment: @jmp Sure thing, hopefully everything is set up right but the apk is located here: https://github.com/dallas-wood/TestApp

Comment: @jmp Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for the delay. I wrote this test with the app and the methods appear successful in Device farm([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD5e2n8XOww&feature=youtu.be) of the tests).

**Test class**

```
package Tests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class DismissPopupTest{

     /**
     * Make the driver static. This allows it to be created only once
     * and used across all of the test classes.
     */
    public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    /**
     * This method runs before any other method.
     *
     * Appium follows a client - server model:
     * We are setting up our appium client in order to connect to Device Farm's appium server.
     *
     * We do not need to and SHOULD NOT set our own DesiredCapabilities
     * Device Farm creates custom settings at the server level. Setting your own DesiredCapabilities
     * will result in unexpected results and failures.
     *
     * @throws MalformedURLException An exception that occurs when the URL is wrong
     */
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUpAppium() throws MalformedURLException {

        final String URL_STRING = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";

        URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);

        //Use a empty DesiredCapabilities object fro device farm
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, capabilities);

        //Use a higher value if your mobile elements take time to show up
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void authTest() {        

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")));   

        MobileElement allowBtn = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"));
        allowBtn.click();

    }



    /**
     * Always remember to quit
     */
    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDownAppium() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    /**
     * Restart the app after every test class to go back to the main
     * screen and to reset the behavior
     */
    @AfterClass
    public void restartApp() {
        driver.resetApp();
    }
}
```

The Appium server log show that the implict wait is set on the driver and the element is found.

**Appium server logs**

```
2018-08-27 04:35:19:589 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/timeouts/implicit_wait {"ms":35000}
2018-08-27 04:35:19:627 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.implicitWait() with args: [35000,"2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8"]
2018-08-27 04:35:19:630 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Set implicit wait to 35000ms
2018-08-27 04:35:19:631 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.implicitWait() result: null
2018-08-27 04:35:19:652 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/timeouts/implicit_wait 200 44 ms - 76 
2018-08-27 04:35:19:725 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element {"using":"id","value":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"}
2018-08-27 04:35:19:727 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8"]
2018-08-27 04:35:19:728 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-27 04:35:19:729 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-27 04:35:19:730 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 35000 ms for condition
2018-08-27 04:35:19:764 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
2018-08-27 04:35:19:785 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
2018-08-27 04:35:19:821 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2018-08-27 04:35:19:822 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
2018-08-27 04:35:19:822 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
2018-08-27 04:35:19:823 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-27 04:35:20:000 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2018-08-27 04:35:20:002 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:007 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"1"}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:032 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element 200 298 ms - 87
```

The element is then clicked and the popup gets dismissed

```
2018-08-27 04:35:20:113 - [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element/1/displayed {}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:114 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.elementDisplayed() with args: ["1","2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8"]
2018-08-27 04:35:20:116 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getAttribute","params":{"attribute":"displayed","elementId":"1"}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:145 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getAttribute","params":{"attribute":"displayed","elementId":"1"}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:145 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2018-08-27 04:35:20:146 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: getAttribute
2018-08-27 04:35:20:162 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2018-08-27 04:35:20:163 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"true"}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:163 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.elementDisplayed() result: true
2018-08-27 04:35:20:178 - [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element/1/displayed 200 76 ms - 76 
2018-08-27 04:35:20:180 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element {"using":"id","value":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:180 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8"]
2018-08-27 04:35:20:181 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-27 04:35:20:182 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
2018-08-27 04:35:20:182 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 35000 ms for condition
2018-08-27 04:35:20:203 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:218 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:235 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2018-08-27 04:35:20:235 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
2018-08-27 04:35:20:236 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
2018-08-27 04:35:20:251 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button]
2018-08-27 04:35:20:258 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2018-08-27 04:35:20:286 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"2"}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:290 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element 200 107 ms - 87 
2018-08-27 04:35:20:311 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:312 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element/2/click {"id":"2"}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:313 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args: ["2","2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8"]
2018-08-27 04:35:20:329 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:348 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
2018-08-27 04:35:20:368 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
2018-08-27 04:35:20:384 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: click
2018-08-27 04:35:23:548 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2018-08-27 04:35:23:550 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: true
2018-08-27 04:35:23:568 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2feb5200-b336-47d5-94ba-63c45d749af8/element/2/click 200 3238 ms - 76
```

Given all the information so far it may be the case that the code test packages or results were mixed up.

I hope this helps.

-James

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `uiautomator2` to run tests in your local, you should also set the `automationName` capability to `uiautomator2` in device farm.

I had the same challenge working with device farm initially, but setting up this capability solved my issue.

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
```

Also, you need not interact with the device to grant any permission to the app. This can be done seamlessly by setting up `autoGrantPermissions` capability. It will grant all the required permissions to your app.

```
capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions",true);
```